# Load CSV, match nodes, merge relationships, and push new values to array property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I match nodes from a CSV load and push values from each match into a relationship's array property?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://example.com/horse_races.csv' AS line
MATCH (j:Jockey { name: line.JOCKEY_NAME})
MATCH (h:Horse { name: line.HORSE_NAME})
MERGE (j)-[r:JOCKEYED]->(h)
ON MATCH SET r.date = r.date + date(line.RACE_DATE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently on `merge` you only set the date on the relationship when there the relationship already exists. You can set `on create` to initialize the list when it doesn't exist yet:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///jockeys.csv' AS line 
with distinct line MATCH (j:Jockey { name: line.JOCKEY_NAME}), (h:Horse { name: line.HORSE_NAME}) 
MERGE (j)-[r:JOCKEYED]->(h) ON CREATE SET r.date = [line.RACE_DATE] 
ON MATCH SET r.date = r.date + date(line.RACE_DATE)
```

Comment: That works. I used the date() function around within the initialization of the list to ensure the value of the first element is formatted properly.